# What is the opposite to [sender resignFirstResponder]; Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, xcode4

Hi I was wondering if there was an opposite to

```
[sender resignFirstResponder];
```

I was wondering because I am doing a login page with 2 UITextFields ("username" and "password") and wanted the username done button to open the keyboard to the password field.

Maybe there's something like

```
[sender assignFirstResponder];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A little bit of docs and the medicine goes down...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`[sender becomeFirstResponder];`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Thanks but I figured that part out myself

Answer (score 0):

```
if(textfield==nameTextfield)
{

[passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```